# Why does "find" only print directories it is searching when there are no test flags?

Tags: bash, shell, find

When I issue something like `sudo find . "*dev/null"` to bash, the shell prints out the directories that match the expression as well as  every single directory that it searches through to find the matches.

When I, however, issue a flag that adds test conditions like `sudo find . -wholename "*dev/null"`, then the shell only prints out the directories that match the expression I am searching for (along with any directories that I do not have permission to access).

I have looked over the man page and I cannot find anything that specifies why adding tests to the `find` command causes it to *not* print every searched directory. Can anyone explain why the `find` command doesn't print in the instances of tests?

Comment: The recent Bourne Shell (`bosh`) is the only shell where a fully working `find` is a builtin command. Well, `busybox` implements a toy version of `find` built into the shell. Since this does not apply to `bash`, it is unimportant which version you are using.

Comment: usage problem. you forgot parameter/flag for given argument, that's why it's treated as *searchdir* and `find` is running without any flags at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `sudo find . "*dev/null"` both `.` and `*dev/null` are *starting points*. There is no explicit test, everything matches. It is almost as if you run

```
sudo find .
sudo find "*dev/null"
```

The latter most likely prints `find: '*dev/null': No such file or directory`, but the former finds *everything* in `.`.

In `sudo find . -wholename "*dev/null"` the fragment `-wholename "*dev/null"` is an actual test.

---

From the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), the following fragments are relevant:

> The `find` utility shall recursively descend the directory hierarchy from each file specified by path, evaluating a Boolean expression composed of the primaries described in the OPERANDS section for each file encountered.

> If no expression is present, `-print` shall be used as the expression.

> `-print`
> The primary shall always evaluate as true; it shall cause the current pathname to be written to standard output.

Your `sudo find . "*dev/null"` is in fact `sudo find . "*dev/null" -print`. There are no tests before `-print` that could make `find` stop evaluating the expression, so for each pathname tested `-print` is reached and therefore each pathname is printed.

More fragments:

> `( expression )`
> True if `expression` is true.

> `expression  [-a]  expression`
> Conjunction of primaries; the AND operator is implied by the juxtaposition of two primaries or made explicit by the optional `-a` operator. The second expression shall not be evaluated if the first expression is false.

> If no expression is present, `-print` shall be used as the expression. Otherwise, if the given expression does not contain any of the primaries `-exec`, `-ok`, or `-print`, the given expression shall be effectively replaced by:
>
> ```
> ( given_expression ) -print
> ```

<sup>Note: implementations may add to the set `-exec`, `-ok`, `-print`.</sup>

Your `sudo find . -wholename "*dev/null"` is equivalent to

```
sudo find . \( -wholename "*dev/null" \) -a -print
```

<sup>(the parentheses are escaped because they are special to the shell).</sup>

Now if `-wholename "*dev/null"` evaluates to false, `-print` will not be evaluated, because this is how `-a` works. This way a failed test for a given pathname prevents `find` from printing the pathname.

---

Notes:

- Non-POSIX extensions should not change the general idea of the tool.
- `-wholename` is not required by POSIX; still in GNU `find` it is equivalent to `-path` which is specified by POSIX.
- You may find [this other answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1577902/432690) interesting.

Comment: `-wholename` is non-standard and thus should not be used. `-path` has been added to POSIX in 2008 and for this reason, you cannot expect it in Solaris 10, AIX or MACOS since these OS have been certified agains POSIX.1-2001. Well MacOS may support it since it uses a FreeBSD userland.